# How to override a module in Clementine Framework

Tags: php

I would like to change the behavior of a Clementine Framework module I have installed.

I know that I should never change the code in `app/share/` as my changes would be destroyed. How do I make them persist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just *override* the function you want. You can override controllers, models, helpers, view blocks and configuration files.

For **controllers**, **models** and **helpers**, you extend the class that defines the code you want to change. Clementine Framework will automatically *use* your code everywhere instead of the code you have overriden.

For example, il you want to override the controller `Users::createAction()` (which is defined in `app/share/users/ctrl/usersUsersController.php`), create a new file `app/local/site/ctrl/siteUsersController.php` looking like this:

```
<?php
class siteUsersController extends siteUsersController_Parent
{
    public function indexAction($request, $params = null)
    {
        //do your specific stuff here
        //then return parent:: function 
        return parent::indexAction($request, $params);
    }
}
```

If you want to override a view **block**, for example the block that is defined in `app/share/users/view/users/index.php`, create a new file `app/local/site/view/users/index.php` looking like this:

```
<?php
//display specific stuff here
//then display parent block
$this->getParentBlock($data, $request);
```

If you want to override some **configuration**, for example the `send_account_confirmation` option that is defined in the `[module_users]` section of file `app/share/users/etc/config.ini`, edit you `app/local/site/etc/config.ini` file, add a `[module_users]` section and override the option:

```
[module_users]
send_account_confirmation="1"
```